# Record test coverage per test case using eclEmma tool

Tags: java, junit, jacoco, emma, eclemma

I want to record test coverage per test case using eclEmma tool. The coverage should contain the % covered by that test case of the target class and also want to access the statements executed by that test case. Follwowing is the code which runs a test class and generates the coverage on test class itself.

```
package expJaCoCo;
public class Calculadora
{
    public Calculadora() { }

    public int add(int x, final int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

CalculadoraTest.java

```
package expJaCoCo;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Test;
public class CalculadoraTest extends TestCase
{
    private Calculadora c1;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() { c1 = new Calculadora(); }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() { c1 = null; }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() { assertTrue(c1.add(1, 0) == 1); }
}
```

CoreTutorial.java

```
package expJaCoCo;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.CoverageBuilder;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.IClassCoverage;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.ICounter;
import org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataStore;
import org.jacoco.core.instr.Instrumenter;
import org.jacoco.core.runtime.IRuntime;
import org.jacoco.core.runtime.LoggerRuntime;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
public class CoreTutorial
{
    /**
     * A class loader that loads classes from in-memory data.
     */
    public static class MemoryClassLoader extends ClassLoader
    {
        private final Map<String, byte[]> definitions = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
        /**
         * Add a in-memory representation of a class.
         * 
         * @param name name of the class
         * @param bytes class definition
         */
        public void addDefinition(final String name, final byte[] bytes) {
            definitions.put(name, bytes);
        }
        @Override
        protected Class<?> loadClass(final String name, final boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException
        {
            final byte[] bytes = definitions.get(name);
            if (bytes != null)
                return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        }
    }
    private InputStream getTargetClass(final String name)
    {
        final String resource = '/' + name.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        return getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
    }
    private void printCounter(final String unit, final ICounter counter)
    {
        final Integer missed    = Integer.valueOf(counter.getMissedCount());
        final Integer total     = Integer.valueOf(counter.getTotalCount());

        System.out.printf("%s of %s %s missed%n", missed, total, unit);
    }
    private String getColor(final int status)
    {
        switch (status) {
        case ICounter.NOT_COVERED:
            return "red";
        case ICounter.PARTLY_COVERED:
            return "yellow";
        case ICounter.FULLY_COVERED:
            return "green";
        }
        return "";
    }
    private void runTutorial() throws Exception
    {
        final String targetName = CalculadoraTest.class.getName();
        // For instrumentation and runtime we need a IRuntime instance to collect execution data:
        final IRuntime runtime = new LoggerRuntime();
        // The Instrumenter creates a modified version of our test target class that contains additional probes for execution data recording:
        final Instrumenter instr = new Instrumenter(runtime);
        final byte[] instrumented = instr.instrument(getTargetClass(targetName));
        // Now we're ready to run our instrumented class and need to startup the runtime first:
        runtime.startup();
        // In this tutorial we use a special class loader to directly load the instrumented class definition from a byte[] instances.
        final MemoryClassLoader memoryClassLoader = new MemoryClassLoader();
        memoryClassLoader.addDefinition(targetName, instrumented);
        final Class<?> targetClass = memoryClassLoader.loadClass(targetName);
        // Here we execute our test target class through its Runnable interface:
        /*final Runnable targetInstance = (Runnable) targetClass.newInstance();
        targetInstance.run();*/
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(targetClass);
        System.out.println(result.getRunTime());
        // At the end of test execution we collect execution data and shutdown the runtime:
        final ExecutionDataStore executionData = new ExecutionDataStore();
        runtime.collect(executionData, null, false);
        runtime.shutdown();
        // Together with the original class definition we can calculate coverage information:
        final CoverageBuilder coverageBuilder = new CoverageBuilder();
        final Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(executionData, coverageBuilder);
        analyzer.analyzeClass(getTargetClass(targetName));
        // Let's dump some metrics and line coverage information:
        for (final IClassCoverage cc : coverageBuilder.getClasses())
        {
            System.out.printf("Coverage of class %s%n", cc.getName());
            printCounter("instructions", cc.getInstructionCounter());
            printCounter("branches", cc.getBranchCounter());
            printCounter("lines", cc.getLineCounter());
            printCounter("methods", cc.getMethodCounter());
            printCounter("complexity", cc.getComplexityCounter());
            for (int i = cc.getFirstLine(); i <= cc.getLastLine(); i++) {
                System.out.printf("Line %s: %s%n", Integer.valueOf(i), getColor(cc.getLine(i).getStatus()));
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        new CoreTutorial().runTutorial();
    }
}
```

This example executes and instrument CalculadoraTest and provide the coverage of CalculadoraTest.java, but I want the coverage of Calculadora.java 
How can I change the code to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This example executes and instrument CalculadoraTest and provide the coverage of CalculadoraTest.java, but I want the coverage of Calculadora.java How can I change the code to get the desired result.

`targetName` that is `CalculadoraTest.class.getName()` is used for both coverage instrumentation/analysis by JaCoCo and execution by JUnit, however in the first case should be `Calculadora.class.getName()`.

Using JaCoCo 0.7.7 APIs:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.CoverageBuilder;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.IClassCoverage;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.ICounter;
import org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataStore;
import org.jacoco.core.instr.Instrumenter;
import org.jacoco.core.runtime.IRuntime;
import org.jacoco.core.runtime.LoggerRuntime;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.jacoco.core.runtime.RuntimeData;
import org.jacoco.core.data.SessionInfoStore;

public class CoreTutorialTest
{
    /**
     * A class loader that loads classes from in-memory data.
     */
    public static class MemoryClassLoader extends ClassLoader
    {
        private final Map<String, byte[]> definitions = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
        /**
         * Add a in-memory representation of a class.
         * 
         * @param name name of the class
         * @param bytes class definition
         */
        public void addDefinition(final String name, final byte[] bytes) {
            definitions.put(name, bytes);
        }
        @Override
        protected Class<?> loadClass(final String name, final boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException
        {
            final byte[] bytes = definitions.get(name);
            if (bytes != null)
                return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
        }
    }
    private InputStream getTargetClass(final String name)
    {
        final String resource = '/' + name.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        return getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
    }
    private void printCounter(final String unit, final ICounter counter)
    {
        final Integer missed    = Integer.valueOf(counter.getMissedCount());
        final Integer total     = Integer.valueOf(counter.getTotalCount());

        System.out.printf("%s of %s %s missed%n", missed, total, unit);
    }
    private String getColor(final int status)
    {
        switch (status) {
        case ICounter.NOT_COVERED:
            return "red";
        case ICounter.PARTLY_COVERED:
            return "yellow";
        case ICounter.FULLY_COVERED:
            return "green";
        }
        return "";
    }
    private void runTutorial() throws Exception
    {
        final String targetName = Calculadora.class.getName();
        // For instrumentation and runtime we need a IRuntime instance to collect execution data:
        final IRuntime runtime = new LoggerRuntime();
        // The Instrumenter creates a modified version of our test target class that contains additional probes for execution data recording:
        final Instrumenter instr = new Instrumenter(runtime);
        final byte[] instrumented = instr.instrument(getTargetClass(targetName), "");
        // Now we're ready to run our instrumented class and need to startup the runtime first:
        final RuntimeData data = new RuntimeData();
        runtime.startup(data);
        // In this tutorial we use a special class loader to directly load the instrumented class definition from a byte[] instances.
        final MemoryClassLoader memoryClassLoader = new MemoryClassLoader();
        memoryClassLoader.addDefinition(targetName, instrumented);
        final Class<?> targetClass = memoryClassLoader.loadClass(targetName);
        // Here we execute our test target class through its Runnable interface:
        /*final Runnable targetInstance = (Runnable) targetClass.newInstance();
        targetInstance.run();*/

        String junitName = CalculadoraTest.class.getName();
        memoryClassLoader.addDefinition(junitName, instr.instrument(getTargetClass(junitName), ""));
        final Class<?> junitClass = memoryClassLoader.loadClass(junitName);
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(junitClass);

        System.out.println("Failure count: " + result.getFailureCount());

        // At the end of test execution we collect execution data and shutdown the runtime:
        final ExecutionDataStore executionData = new ExecutionDataStore();
        data.collect(executionData, new SessionInfoStore(), false);
        runtime.shutdown();
        // Together with the original class definition we can calculate coverage information:
        final CoverageBuilder coverageBuilder = new CoverageBuilder();
        final Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(executionData, coverageBuilder);
        analyzer.analyzeClass(getTargetClass(targetName), targetName);
        // Let's dump some metrics and line coverage information:
        for (final IClassCoverage cc : coverageBuilder.getClasses())
        {
            System.out.printf("Coverage of class %s%n", cc.getName());
            printCounter("instructions", cc.getInstructionCounter());
            printCounter("branches", cc.getBranchCounter());
            printCounter("lines", cc.getLineCounter());
            printCounter("methods", cc.getMethodCounter());
            printCounter("complexity", cc.getComplexityCounter());
            for (int i = cc.getFirstLine(); i <= cc.getLastLine(); i++) {
                System.out.printf("Line %s: %s%n", Integer.valueOf(i), getColor(cc.getLine(i).getStatus()));
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        new CoreTutorial().runTutorial();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but when JUnit runs the `CalculadoraTest.class` it runs the test case on `Calculadora.class` instead of running it on the instrumented `Calculadora.class` . So the question is how to force the `CalculadoraTest.class` to run the test cases on the instrumented `Calculadora.class`

Comment: when I run it using the code( [Click here for the code that I am using](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B-s5qXvG3IDCEhzyKiq1xZtAEftc1ZNhTSfBQv4JcfE/edit?usp=sharing) ) it does show the coverage on the target class, i.e., Calculadora.class, but it fails all the test cases

Comment: @PiyushNariani pasted full code into an answer it prints `Failure count: 0` and coverage of `Calculadora.class`